# Parsing XML field for value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking to do a WHERE on an XML field. The code below is an example of what I've got so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM @TEMP
WHERE xmltest.exist('/Attributes/Attribute[upper-case(@name)="TEST"]/text()[upper-case(.) = "A1"]') = 1
```

The problem is that my TEST attribute can contain comma-separated fields like A1,3,A12 and I would need to tokenize those and look for the specific value (contains won't work here). I know SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `tokenize()`, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you show a couple of sample XML column values?

Comment: Why oh why is everybody sticking multiple values into a comma-separated list? What a brain-dead design "non-pattern" ...

Comment: @marc_s: I can tell you that this wasn't my idea.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: They are just comma-separated alphanumeric strings.

Comment: Understood, but it would still be useful to see an actual example. If it's just a comma separated string then it's not XML, is it?